# Does equivariance of the MLE require the function be invertible?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, equivariant-maps

My statistics text states this theorem as if it works for any function $g$:

> Let $\tau = g(\theta)$ be a function of $\theta$. Let $\hat{\theta}_n$
>   be the MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimator) of $\theta$. Then
>   $\hat{\tau}_n = g(\hat{\theta}_n)$ is the MLE of $g(\theta)$.

And offers this proof that seems to assume $g$ has an inverse:

> Proof. Let $h = g^{-1}$ denote the inverse of $g$. Then
>   $\hat{\theta}_n = h(\hat{\tau}_n)$. For any $\tau$, $\mathcal{L}(\tau)
>  = \prod_i f(x_i; h(\tau)) = \prod_i f(x_i;\theta) = \mathcal{L}(\theta)$ where $\theta = h(\tau)$. Hence, for any $\tau$,
>   $\mathcal{L}_n(\tau) = \mathcal{L}(\theta) \leq
>  \mathcal{L}(\hat{\theta}) = \mathcal{L}_n(\hat{\tau})$.

Is an inverse required? Maybe the author is assuming one for a simpler proof? Also I'm not sure where the inequality is coming from?

I tried reading the Wikipedia article on equivariant maps (my statistics text is my first exposure to the term) but it uses too much material I haven't learned yet.

Comment: I think, it doesn't require the inverse. But my memory is hazy(so please verify), usually they define a new likelihood function in terms of old one.

Comment: No it does not require the function to be invertible, *any* function will do. Here is the original paper by Zehna: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177699475.

Comment: @StubbornAtom But the Math Reviews article about that paper is scathing.

Comment: @kimchilover This is among the first works on this topic, hence my mention of the article. I would ask the OP to see the proof on Casella-Berger's *Statistical Inference* where I think a better insight is provided.

Comment: Is it possible that somebody explain the proof and why it holds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not necessary that $g$ is invertible. See page 320 of [Casella and Berger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534243126). The proof of the property is, however, much simpler when $g$ is invertible.